# I would like to reply to a 'target' tweet(s) using Twit on Node.js: But I have no clue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

So currently the tweet bot is;

---

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    Twit = require('twit'),
    config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.js'));
    var T = new Twit(config);

function pick_random_countermagic(){
  var countermagic = [
    'Force-of-Will.jpg',
    'Cryptic-Commad.jpg',
    'Counterspell.jpg',
  ];
  return countermagic[Math.floor(Math.random() * countermagic.length)];
}

function upload_random_image(){
  console.log('Opening an image...');
  var image_path = path.join(__dirname, '/countermagic/' + pick_random_countermagic()),
      b64content = fs.readFileSync(image_path, { encoding: 'base64' });

  console.log('Uploading an image...');

  T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
    if (err){
      console.log('ERROR');
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log('Uploaded an image!');

      T.post('statuses/update', {
        media_ids: new Array(data.media_id_string)
      },
        function(err, data, response) {
          if (err){
            console.log('Error!');
            console.log(err);
          }
          else{
            console.log('Posted an image!');
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
}

setInterval(
  upload_random_image,
  10000
);
```

---

All it does currently posts, at random an image, which is what I want, but instead of just posting it I would like it to post in reply to a targeted tweet from another twitter when that bot tweets, and or when the bot is active reply to all tweets that bot has tweeted that my bot has not already replied to... if you know what I mean.

This is my first time making a twitter bot, and technically my first time really using javascript and node.js. So yeah, I am just lost. So yeah any help would be insurmountably helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve mentions using [statuses/mentions_timeline API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/mentions_timeline) and reply them using [statuses/update API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update) by passing mention's id in `in_reply_to_status_id`. Here is a simple example:

```
function replyMentions() {
    // check for mentions
    // you can add parameter 'since_id' to limit returns
    T.get('statuses/mentions_timeline', { count: 100 }, function(err, data, response) {
      if (data) {
          data.forEach(function(mention) {
             // reply if mention.id_str is not yet replied
             reply = '@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' thanks for reaching out!'
             T.post('statuses/update', { status: reply, in_reply_to_status_id: mention.id_str }, function(err, data, response) {
               console.log(data)
               // mark data.id_str as replied
             })
          })
      }
    })
}
```

You can add some additional logic to store replied `id_str` in database and use them to avoid redundant replies and limiting mentions retrieval (using `since_id` parameter).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton, I will try and implement this tonight. And comeback you comment the result.

Comment: So this was sort of what I was looking for; But not exactly, I want it to reply to the most recent tweet(s) the bot has not replied to, of a specific user without being mentioned.

var nameID = tweet.id_str;

var name = tweet.user.screen_name;

T.post('statuses/update', {in_reply_to_status_id: nameID, status: reply + ' ' + number + ' @' + name}, function(err, data, response) {

Something like this; But with the image.

Comment: As I have mentioned, twitter doesn't give a straightforward flag/mark telling whether a mention has been replied or not. So you could keep track whenever you reply or call [statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) to check your own tweets and check `in_reply_to_status_id_str`. As for image, you have to upload it first using [media/upload](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload) then include the `media_id` in `statuses/update`'s `media_ids`

Comment: Well, that's, annoying. Uhg... well thank you anyway and for the directions to some resources. Eeh I will think of something.